# Audio compression in Windows Store apps?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, mp3, ogg, wma

I'm looking for a way to compress wav files to some other format - mp3, wma or ogg. Is there any library I could use? Lame would not work in a WinStore app, or would it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is transcoding support in the [Windows.Media.Transcoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.transcoding) namespace. There is a [sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Media-Transcode-Sample-f7ba5269#content) for video but audio should be supported too. Looking at [MediaEncodingProfile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701026.aspx) it seems aac, wma and mp3 are supported.

*EDIT (usage sample)

```
var profile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp3(AudioEncodingQuality.High);
var transcoder = new MediaTranscoder();
var folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
var mp3File = await folder.CreateFileAsync(
    mp3FileName,
    CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
var transcode = await transcoder.PrepareFileTranscodeAsync(wavFile, mp3File, profile);
await transcode.TranscodeAsync();
```

Comment: I spent a week wondering how I will do the compression if it is not available and here it just is! And to think of it I think I have seen that class a couple of months ago. Bah! Let me check if I can just do it.

Comment: Yup, thanks, works easily. Added a code snippet for how I used it.